# Why I would create another Catalog beside the default one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, full-text-search

I am new to Full Text Search of Sql server.  Why I would create another Catalog beside the default one?

I actually don't understand how exactly catalog organize full text indices, I had impression that it is just like a schema to a table.  please verify that to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It appears that it is not possible to add a second Full Text catalog to the same table.  On SQL Server 2008R2, once I've added a catalog, the button to add another is disabled:

[image]

You can add 2 eligible columns to the same catalog though:

[image]

More advice on FTS:

[Database Journal - Setting up full text search: A step-by-step guide](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/1438211/Setting-Up-Full-Text-Search-A-Step-by-step-Guide.htm)

[MSDN - SQL Server Best Practices - Full Text Search](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917695.aspx#EBAA)